# How to serve a PDF in Express/Node and download in client button?

Tags: node.js, express, rest, pdf, get

I have an Express/Node server with an endpoint to provide the PDF, and a React client that is making a get request to that endpoint.

Currently the PDF is in what I believe is raw pdf binary data string form (obtained from the response of a separate api request), and on the client side I want to click a button in the browser and have the PDF download.

I'm not sure what is needed on the server side and on the client side to successfully trigger
the download on request.

Do I need to convert the binary PDF data to something on the server side first? Or does this get handled on the client side?

And what would be the code to do this?

Server:

```
const servePDF = async (req, res) => {
    const pdfBinary = '%PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 2 0 obj <</ColorSpa ......'

    ~code here to send pdf as response~
}
```

Client:

```
const downloadPDF = async () => {
    ~get request code here, to run onClick of a button, to download file~
}
```